# How to handle mouseover and mouseleave events in Windows 8.1 Touchscreen

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-10

In my asp.net project, I have written javascript functions on mouseover and mouseleave/ mouseout events of buttons and some other controls. Previously this website was used on non touchscreen devices. But now when I am trying to access the same website on Windows 8.1 , on Internet Explorer 10/11,the problem is, after touching a screen mouse click event is fired (which is ok in my case)and when I remove finger on screen, mouseleave event is fired (which is problematic e.g. dropdowns are not working properly after mouseleave events fired). This Problem arises only in Internet Explorer 10/11. And the site is working fine with all its functionality on Chrome. Is there any JQuery Plugin or some other solution for this problem? Please reply soon. I need this very urgently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add `aria-haspopup="true"` attribute to element triggering dropdown showing/hiding.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj152135(v=vs.85).aspx